# How select in multitable a single column where the price is greater than "0"?

Tags: c#, linq

i have 5 tables how follow below :

**City_TBL**

```
CityCode
```

---

```
   ABB
   DET
   FRI
   ROM
```

**Hotel_TBL**

```
HotelCode           CityCode (FK)      Price
```

---

```
    1                   ABB              0
    2                   ABB              10
    3                   FRI              0
    4                   DET              0
    5                   ROM              19
```

**HotelRoom_TBL**

```
RoomID         HotelCode (FK)      RoomName     Price
```

---

```
    1                   1          Superior       3
    2                   2          DeLuxe         6
    3                   1          Panoramic      0
    4                   3          Suite          0
    5                   4          Presidential   1
```

**Transfer_TBL**

```
TransferCode         CityCode (FK)      Price
```

---

```
    1                   ABB              3
    2                   ABB              6
    3                   DET              0
    4                   FRI              0
```

**Cruise_TBL**

```
CruiseCode         CityCode (FK)      Price
```

---

```
    1                   ABB              3
    2                   DET              0
    3                   FRI              0
    4                   ROM              0
```

I want write down a query(linq) which will return  a list of CityCode without duplicate record(CityCode) in which has at least a record where the field/Column "Price" (in the Table Hotel_TBL , Transfer_TBL  ,  Cruise_TBL and HotelRoom_TBL) is greater then '0' as follow result as show  below :

```
Result_TBL
```

---

```
   ABB
   ROM
```

How i can do it with linq to sql ?

Thanks so much for your attention.

Have a good time.

Cheers

Sorry i modified the question 'cos i forgot to write down another table(HotelRoom_TBL) so please forgive me this mistake .
Thank so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
var data = 
    ctx.HotelTbl.Where(row => row.Price > 0).Select(row => row.CityCode)
    .Union(
     ctx.TransferTbl.Where(row => row.Price > 0).Select(row => row.CityCode)
    ).Union(
     ctx.ResultTbl.Where(row => row.Price > 0).Select(row => row.CityCode)
    );
```

Personally I'd be tempted to use ExecuteQuery though:

```
var data = ctx.ExecuteQuery<string>(@"
select CityCode from Hotel_Tbl where Price > 0
union select CityCode from Transfer_Tbl where Price > 0
union select CityCode from Result_Tbl where Price > 0").ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks so much mr.Marc the code is right but i forgot to insert another table so please try to sympathize for my mistake.

Comment: yes Marc that's works very nice...Thanks so much for your support wishing you a nice day too.